# Will Cloudflare Page Rules deal with AngularJS HTML5 mode 404 issue

Tags: angularjs, cloudflare

I am tinkering with my AngularJS 1 site again, trying to get rid of hash bangs.

I have set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in my **app.js** and I have added `<base href="/">` inside the page's  tag.  Of course it works fine when I click a link, but it all falls apart with a 404 error if I refresh or try to go to a page directly.

My site is hosted on Github Pages and I am configuring CloudFlare in front of it.   I was curious if I can configure one of CloudFlare's free page rules to properly deal with the hash bang.  Or is this something that can only be done with IIS/Express/Apache?

---

**Routing code snippet:**

```
var app = angular.module('eat-sleep-code', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']); 

/* Routing */
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {    
        $routeProvider.      
            /* Root */
            when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'views/contact.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/privacy', {templateUrl: 'views/privacy.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/resources', {templateUrl: 'views/resources.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/terms', {templateUrl: 'views/terms.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Comment: Your routing code .

Comment: Added routing code

Comment: Remove that `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` from your routing. This will solve problem.

Comment: How will that solve the problem?  Removing it would disable html5Mode (as the default value is false), meaning it will ONLY work with hashbangs.  I am trying to get rid of the hashbangs.

Comment: May I know, why you want to getrid of hashbangs?

Comment: 1.) They look hokey and 2.) they negatively affect search engine indexing.

Comment: You are using html5Mode. It removes '#' from your url, that's common issue - after reloading page it won't render, because you have basically single page application, and routes after '#' are virtual. Without this sign, you will see only root(home) page. So, refreshing treatrs it to be home. So, can't get data. Better use hashbang mode.

Comment: Hence why my question is whether the CloudFlare rules can be user to rewrite the URL.

Comment: Sorry, not understood that point.

Comment: Set the CloudFlare rule to have `*example.com/myapp*` forward to `https://www.example.com/myapp#$2`. The `$2` represents the text matched by the second wildcard. This will convert paths to hash fragments that the router can parse.

Comment: Is this possible if the app sits at the root of the domain?  Or would it end up doing an endless loop?

Comment: I received email back from Cloudflare support that this is not possible (at least as of today, January 5, 2017).   I guess I will be stuck with hashbang for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received email back from Cloudflare support that this is not possible (at least as of today, January 5, 2017). I guess I will be stuck with hashbang for now.